# when i hit index page instead of error messages I'm just getting a blank page.PHP

Tags: php, html, linux

when i hit index page instead of error messages I'm just getting a blank page. Is there any way to show PHP error messages instead? It's very hard to debug when I get no feedback.  My environment is linux. PHP

Comment: More details needed.

Comment: try adding `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to your code

Comment: i am having all html pages on server. but for enquiry form i have added PHPmailer to index page. and changed the extension to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Basically you have to add this 2 lines at the beginning of the file

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: Warning: require(PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cc97320023/public_html/index.php on line 5

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cc97320023/public_html/index.php on line 5

Comment: but i have PHPMailer folder with all files

Comment: when i use wampserver it works all fine on local server but not online

Comment: The reason why its not working on your online server could be the php.ini, another place where you can activate/deactivate those warnings.

Comment: About the PHP Mailer... it says that is lookin in the folder include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php', that is automatically included, there is where PHP Mailer should be, but as I can't see your application I don't know if it is already there.

Comment: which setting i do have to change in .ini?

Comment: As @catzilla told you a couple answers up, change display_errors  and set it to ON and then restart apache sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: k i will try and let you know.. thanx for helping

Answer (score 5):

there are more than one way to show errors in php scripts in linux..

**first**, in your index.php file, insert this codes:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

this enables displaying errors and warning from your browser..

or **second**, open `php.ini` file located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and edit the line

```
display_errors = Off
```

to

```
display_errors = On
```

and restart apache2

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**NOTE:** the first method only enables error message on the current file while the second method globally enables error messages to all php scripts..

sources:
[display error message](http://matthewwittering.com/blog/ubuntu-tips/php-error-messages.html), [show errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings)

Comment: try using the linux's terminal and just type `sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/ini.php` or just locate it using `locate ini.php`

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File /home/cc97320023/public_html/php.ini

Comment: and i dont know where usr folder is located.. i dont see any

Comment: then I suggest modifying that php.ini file on where you found it... usr folder is located at the bottom of the file system... try using `cd /usr` and you can access that folder